# Does God allow a person to stay a bachelor throughout his life in Islam if he cannot manage the responsibility of marriage?

Tags: nikah, practical-islam

In Islam, there is a lot of importance to marriage. If a person cannot manage the responsibility of marriage as he has some problem in his life that he cannot get married at all, is it the will of Allah that the person shouldn't get married if he has some problem in his life that stops the person from getting married but still practice Islam? I want some clarification on this.